# Conflict between siunitx and sansmath?

Tags: siunitx, sans-serif

I use the following preamble to get a sans serif font in my docs:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

The `siunitx` package works well with this, producing all its output in the same sans serif font as the surrounding text.

But when I try to make the maths sans serif as well:

```
\usepackage{sansmath}
\sansmath
```

The maths outputs in sans serif, but anything from `siunitx` eg `\num{2.3e-5}` now outputs in the standard serif font!

Is there a way to get everything in sans serif font?

Comment: Try with `\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}`

Comment: @HarishKumar ^^^^^

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It didn't work for me though.

Comment: Can you please add your working code? because for me `\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}` doesn't work.