# Siunitx and Sansmath: In-math units return serifed

Tags: siunitx

I've read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244090/conflict-between-siunitx-and-sansmath) regarding a "possible conflict" of the `siunitx` and the `sansmath` packages, but that didn't really solve my issue.

I have a document where the text is written in roman font while the math uses sans serif fonts (thanks to the `libertine` and `sansmath` packages). Here's the preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\sisetup{text-rm=\sffamily,math-rm=\mathsf}

\usepackage{sansmath}
\sansmath
```

I've noticed that whenever I put any of the `siunitx` commands inside the math "environment" (`$ ... $`), the output seems to "ignore" that it's supposed to use sans. Here's my MWE, without using the `libertine` packages.

```
\begin{document}

Let \ang{30} be an acute angle. Also, \num{30} is a number and
\SI{30}{\metre} is not that far!

Let $\ang{30}$ be an acute angle. Also, $\num{30}$ is a number and
$\SI{30}{\metre}$ is not that far!
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: output of the mwe]

What am I doing wrong? It's not mandatory, but all the other numbers inside the math spaces are "sans", so I'd like the bottom line to also show up as sans.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `sfmath` package instead of `sansmath` seems to work with `siunitx` (i.e. you don't need to change `siunitx` font preferences at all).

If that is not an option, setting the number in text mode does the trick:

```
\sisetup{
  mode=text,
  text-rm=\sffamily,
}
```